# Is it possible to get the return value and method arguments from the same advice in Spring AOP?

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

Is it possible to get the return value and method arguments from the same advice in Spring AOP?

I am trying to implement some login based on return value and the method arguments.

All this info needs to be used in the advice to implement my business logic.

For example:

```
MyObject testMethod(String arg 1, String arg2){
    ..
    ..
    return myObject;
}
```

For this case I need myObject, arg1 and arg2 all.

I tried below code with two different annotations: @After and @AfterReturning as given below:

```
@AfterReturning(value="execution(* com.example.aop.service.TestServiceImpl.printTestData(..))", returning="test")
public void checkSomethingAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint, Test test) {
    System.out.println("------------AFTER RETURNING-----------");
    System.out.println("After execution - 111 " + joinPoint.getArgs());
    System.out.println("After execution - test: " + test);
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
}

// @After(value = "execution(* com.example.aop.service.TestServiceImpl.printTestData(..)) and args()")
    @After(value = "execution(* com.example.aop.service.TestServiceImpl.printTestData(..)) && args(id)")
    public void afterAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint, int id) {
        System.out.println("After method:" + joinPoint.getSignature());
        System.out.println("Creating Test with id - " + id);
    }
```

The problem is, I get the arguments in @After and return value in @Afterreturning. My requirement is to get both the return value and arguments in a one method at the same time.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is indeed possible. You need the @Around advice and read the arguments from the ProceedingJoinPoint.

```java
 @Around("execution(* com.example.MyClass.testMethod(..))")
 public Object testAop(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    Object[] arguments = pjp.getArgs();
    Object result = pjp.proceed();
    // Do logic based on arguments + return value

    return result;
}
```

I do feel the implementation might become a bit sketchy so if it's not a real cross-cutting concern then perhaps it is best to write your own delegate around the method.

Comment: Could you please explain more with respect to the updated post please?

Comment: @SwapnilHadge This answers your question: use `@Around`. Your update just shows you tried `@After` and `@AfterReturning`, so it is unclear what Nico would need to address, as the answer is still "use `@Around`".

Comment: here the around advice would call twice that is before and after.
I need both method arg and return value in the same method so that I can apply some business logic based on both the values. Here what happens is on first time, I get method args and on next execution, I get the return value. But I dont get both the method args and return value in single execution.

Comment: @SwapnilHadge Your understanding of `@Around` is incorrect. Only `pjp.proceed()` will execute the underlying method. There is no such thing as _call twice_ or  _next execution_

Comment: Yeah..! Thanks Nico for your explanation. I understood the concept and the issue as well. Marking the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do using `@AfterReturning` annotation too.
Here is an example.

Assume we have this method in `com.test.TestService` class:

```
public Object test(String arg1, Integer arg2) { ... }
```

Then your advice method will look like this:

```
@AfterReturning(
        pointcut="execution(* com.test.TestService.test(..)) && args(arg1,arg2)",
        argNames="arg1,arg2,returnedValue",
        returning="returnedValue")
public void logAfterTest(String arg1, Integer arg2, Object returnedValue) {
    // some logic
}
```